# A simple algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\displaystyle \frac{a^n + b^n}{a^{n-1} + b^{n-1}}$ , ( $a \neq b$ and $a,b,n \in \mathbb{R}$) is the Arithmetic mean **or** Geometric mean between $a$ and $b$ then find the values of $n$ for both means respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by "Arithmetic mean / Geometric mean"? There is an $n$ for each kind of mean?

Comment: This is not my homework,this comes from my test paper, the solution given is is -1/2 ans -1 receptively. Arithmetic mean and geometric mean are seems similar to the concept of A.M and G.M respectively of the sequence and series chapter in higher algebra.

Comment: @Debanjan: What Kenny TM, was thinking was perhaps, whether quantity given is a A.M or a G.M or both.

Comment: @Debanjan: For $n=1$ clearly the quantity represents an A.M between the numbers $a$ and $b$. And it is still unclear as to what you want.

Comment: @Debanjan: Hey what did "/" stand for in your question. I thought it stood for divides. If not then please tell me i shall edit again.

Comment: @ KennyTM: My bad.It's now working correct :) Btw I am inquisitive to know what application are you using to format the equation ?

Comment: If $a=b$ then any $n$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: @Debanjan: Is $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You are saying the answer to be -1/2, -1. So you should mentioned that $n$ need not be an natural number.

Comment: I edited, I think it's stands good now,anyways this is an objective type problem and the problem-setter haven't mentioned these restrictions.

Comment: @Deb: (1) http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117; (2) If so then your answers (-1/2, -1) are incorrect. We get the AM with n = 1, not n = -1/2.

Comment: Sorry the given answer is for A.M , n = -1 and for G.M answer is 1/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the current version of the problem the answer is $n=1$ (for arithmetic mean) and $n=1/2$ (for geometric mean).

Consider first the case
$$
\frac{a^n + b^n}{a^{n-1} + b^{n-1}} = \frac{a + b}{2}
$$
This equality implies $2a^n + 2b^n = a^{n} + ab^{n-1} + b^{n} + ba^{n-1}$. Hence $a^n + b^n = ab^{n-1} + ba^{n-1}$ and so $(a^{n-1} - b^{n-1})(a-b) = 0$. Hence (since $a \ne b$) we have $n=1$. It's easy to check that $n=1$ indeed satisfies the conditions.

Now consider the case
$$
\frac{a^n + b^n}{a^{n-1} + b^{n-1}} = \sqrt{ab}
$$
This equality implies $a^n + b^n = a^{n-1/2}\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a}b^{n-1/2}$. Hence $(a^{n-1/2} - b^{n-1/2})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}) = 0$. So (since $a \ne b$) we have $n=1/2$. It's easy to check that $n=1/2$ indeed satisfies the conditions.

Comment: This is very correct,since your answers matches the options given there, I believes there is some printing mistakes in the printed solutions.

Comment: With n = 0 we get the harmonic mean, and with n = ±∞ we get the maximum/minimum. These seems to be the only 5 points where OP's expression and the power mean $\sqrt[p]{\frac{a^p+b^p}2}$ coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Put $\rm\ A = a^{n-1},\ B = b^{n-1}\:$ below and the results follow immediately

$\rm\displaystyle\quad \frac{a\:A+b\:B}{A+B}\ =\ \frac{a+b}2\ \iff\ (a-b)\ (A-B)\ =\ 0$

$\rm\displaystyle\quad \frac{a\:A+b\:B}{A+B}\ = \ \ \sqrt{ab}\ \ \ \:\iff\ (\sqrt a - \sqrt b)\ (A\sqrt{a}-B\sqrt{b})\ =\ 0$